# ODI KM Option - Calling Project Variable

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

Modifying ODI knowledge Module (KM) to run an if condition using a Project variable. Rather then using the Global variable directly in the code, I want to store the variable in Option and call using GetOption method.

I have created a Option "Option1" and set the value to variable #GLOBAL.VAR1

Value of variable VAR1 is either 1 or 0.

```
<%for (int i=odiRef.getDataSetMin(); i <= odiRef.getDataSetMax(); i++){%>
<%=odiRef.getDataSet(i, "Operator")%>
select  <%=odiRef.getPop("DISTINCT_ROWS")%>
    <%=odiRef.getColList(i, ""," [EXPRESSION]\t[ALIAS_SEP] [CX_COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "", "")%>
from    <%=odiRef.getFrom(i)%>
where
<%if (odiRef.getOption("Option1").equals("1"))  { %>
(1=2)
<%} else {%>
(1=1)
<% } %>
<%}%>
```

Code always generate the else statement. What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: I need a bit more information. What is the datatype of the variable? What is the "Keep History" value? If you run it with log level 6, what is the value of the variable in the operator for that step?
Also I believe your code would be easier with this WHERE clause : `where
<%=odiRef.getOption("Option1")> = 0`

Comment: Data type of the variable is Numeric with latest value. To be honest, the code I have pasted is just an example. Rather then  (1=1) and (1=2), I have a more complex clause based on columns. So above way is not possible for me. Using `<%=odiRef.getOption("Option1")>` substitutes #GLOBAL.VAR1 but how to use it inside an <%if statement is something I am trying to find out.

Comment: Hi vinny, you said that you don't know how to use `<%=odiRef.getOption("Option1")%>`.  You can use it like this `<? variable_name=<%=odiRef.getOption("Option1")%> ?>`; and then use the new variable_name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your if statement does like this:

```
if("#PROJECT_VARIABLE.NAME".equals("1")) ...
```

So you are not evaluating the value, but the name of the variable that you put in the KM option.

Try to store the variable name into another substitution variable, in order to be substituted in the next level, like this:

```
<@ variable_name=<%=odiRef.getOption("Option1")%> @>
```

Comment: I did that and it still doesn't work. My if clause `<$ if  ("#GLOBAL.VAR1".equals("1"))  { $> (1=2) <$} else {$>  (1=1) <$ } $>`

Comment: @vinny, try between <@> not <$> .. it seems that global variables can be read only in <@> tags